# typecasting with if let 'someClass' as? SomeClass and binding to 'someClass.'someProp' does not work

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following construct

```
import SwiftUI

class TopClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someArr = [SomeClass(), SomeSubclass()]
}

class SomeClass: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
}

class SomeSubclass: SomeClass {
    var toggle = true
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var topClass = TopClass()
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($topClass.someArr) {
            $value in
            if let someSubclass = $value as? SomeSubclass  {
                Toggle("Test", isOn: someSubclass.toggle)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I can`t figure out if it is possible to somehow bind ***someSubclass*.toggle** to ***isOn*** of the ***Toggle***. I solution or a hint to where I could research this would be very appreciated.

Comment: This architecture seems like a direction you may want to avoid. Are you aware that using classes for your model like this will mean that changes to the `@Published` array won't actually propagate to your views without manually calling `objectWillChange` on your ObservedObject?

Comment: You may be right and I have to consider adjusting my architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really hell-bent on using this approach, then try this example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var topClass = TopClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($topClass.someArr) { $value in
            if let someSubclass = $value.wrappedValue as? SomeSubclass  {
                Toggle("test", isOn: Binding<Bool> (
                    get: { someSubclass.toggle },
                    set: {
                        topClass.objectWillChange.send()
                        someSubclass.toggle = $0
                    })
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```